# Facebook graph api search people

Tags: facebook, api, graph

I was using facebook graph api people search with;

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=user&q=name&limit=20&fields=id,picture,name&access_token=access_token_id
```

It was working last month. When i checked today it is giving empty data;

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Api versin is 2.6 any suggestions or knowledge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

It is no longer possible to search for users, no matter which API version.